# Update non-null field with possibly null values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

In the query below:

```
update collect_irc_deploy c
set hid = (select id
           from auth_hierarchy
           where fqdn = (select location
                         from reserve
                         where id=c.rid
                        )
          )
where hid = 0 and rid is not null
```

the subquery `select id from auth_hierarchy where fqdn = (select location from reserve where id = c.rid)` may return `NULL` while the field `hid` is `NOT NULL`.

How can I modify the statement so that if the subquery returns NULL that data item is **skipped** instead of failing the entire execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use update...join syntax to ensure only joined rows are updated:

```
update collect_irc_deploy
join reserve on reserve.id = collect_irc_deploy.rid
join auth_hierarchy on auth_hierarchy.fqdn = reserve.location
set collect_irc_deploy.hid = auth_hierarchy.id
where collect_irc_deploy.hid = 0 and collect_irc_deploy.rid is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UPDATE IGNORE` solved my problem.  But it will generate warning messages.